# MYSQL Update one table with the values other table qualified using 2 columns

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have been trying to get this query to work and hoping someone can give  me some advice.

I have two tables.  master and aux.  I need master to be updated with any rows that are in aux and not in master based on groupid and section id.

I need to actually do this with multiple aux tables, but as long as I can figure out how to do it on one, I can just manually run the query on each table I need.

So far I've just been trying to use a select to get the data from aux that should be inserted into master.   Once I have that I can modify it to create the insert query.  (I hope)

```
select 
   a.id 
from 
   master as m, 
   aux as a
where 
   a.gid = m.groupid 
and 
   a.sid = m.sectionid 
and 
   not in m.groupid 
and 
   not in m.sectionid
```

This query is not working :(

***master table***

```
id    groupid    sectionid
1     A Group    21
2     A Group    23
3     B Group    55
4     C Group    999
5     D Group    52A
6     D Group    53
```

***aux table***

```
id    gid        sid
1     A Group    21
2     A Group    22
3     A Group    23
4     B Group    55
5     B Group    55A
6     C Group    999
7     D Group    52A
8     D Group    53
9     D Group    56
```

***master table after query***

```
id    groupid    sectionid
1     A Group    21
2     A Group    23
3     B Group    55
4     C Group    999
5     D Group    52A
6     D Group    53
7     A Group    22
8     B Group    55A
9     D Group    56
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try my answer,  if you need one for multiple tables, just let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think `and not in m.groupid` is valid sql.
A `not exist` with a sub-select should do the trick:

```
insert into master (groupid, sectionid)
select a.gid, a.sid
from aux as a
where not exists(
  select *
  from master as m
  where m.groupid = a.gid
  and a.sid = m.sectionid
)
```

Comment: Good answer bud and thanks for the advice on mine.  I just happened to get it in 1 minute before you.   :)  I gave you an upvote at least

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this...

```
select 
    id 
from 
    aux as a
where 
    not exists (
        select 
            id 
        from 
            master 
        where 
            groupid = a.gid 
        and 
            sectionid = a.sectionid
    )
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/737c4/5)

Comment: Wow, that was quick! I'll go try that.

Comment: why do you want it to not exist rows that are different?  You want it to not exist a row that is the same.

Comment: this query will return no results.  There will always exist a row that is different in the other table.  See my answer above.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I had to change it around a bit but it worked :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  Sorry got a little mixed up on the query, but happy it worked for you.  :)